# How do I testing large complex code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a legacy code that contains little more than a 8700 lines with each method on average around 200-300 lines long. I was wondering how am I able to cover most of those code even to get an output of a successful result.

For example:

```
    public class Aviation implements FlightStruct, FlightSystem extends Vehicles {
    ...var decoration...
    ...override method definitions...

    public controls aviation(Flight request, Flight destination, Flight target) {

    FlightResponse flightResponse = new FlightResponse();

    flightResponse.speed = target.speed;
    angularVel.calculate(greatCircle.flightResponse.speed);
    _readVelData();
    if (vel.circular.velocity <= 10000) {
    for(countryName : country) {
    calculateArrivalTime();
    _readFuel();
    if(fuel.limit < pwi.percent*100) {
           createShortPathLandingPoint(Path newDestination, Register checkPoint);
       }
    }
}
    private eqiptment company(String name, Vendor vendor) {
    ....calculate equiptment stuff that calls bunch of private methods
    }

 ...alot more method here
    }
}
```

I was wondering how should I go about to unit test these kind of code?
I have attempted to stubb data but the inner method is too complicated to walk through. Usually one method calls down multiple layers of sub methods.
For example....
the fuel class calls _readfuel and in _readfuel it calls destinationCheckPoint, flightWayPoint, flightSpeedCalc...then in each of those sub method it calls its own sub method. (ex. flightWaypoint calls calculateWayPoint, angVelocity, speedLimit, ....)
Overall I do not think this is doable by stubbing the data because finding the right data is difficult.
Then My second option was to use Mockito to mock the method / classes. Which sounds more reasonable to do, but again I encounter where there are multiple sub method which are private...and mockito cannot mock the private method. I then attempted to use PowerMockito to mock the private method it work for a few thousand lines and there was something like this:

```
while (!report.successful && !telCList.isEmpty()) {
...
report.wayPoint = update.assignWayPoint(wayPointList); //null point exception
...
```

where the update was null and few hundred lines above it was declared

```
 UpdateGateWay update = setDestinationWayPoint(distance, speed, altitude);
```

setDestinationWayPoint is a private method and I use powerMockito to mock the behavior I have also returned the value as part of the stub. but when it get called below it become null.

I pretty much give up at this point. I was wondering if there would be more reasonable way to do this type of testing....

Answer (score 2):

Writing worthwhile *de novo* unit tests for a legacy codebase that you don't understand is a difficult task.  Especially, if the code is a mess; e.g. *"each method on average around 200-300 lines long"*.

The problem is how to figure out what the methods >>should<< do with sufficient accuracy to write the unit tests.  Unfortunately, that often requires deeper insight than simply understanding how the code *as written* behaves.

It is not an impossible task, but it could be a lot of work ... depending on the code's intrinsic complexity, the quality of the original design, the requirements, the problem domain, etcetera.

A possible alternative would be to treat the code-base as a black box.  Instead of writing unit tests, write system tests based on a number of "typical" scenarios; e.g. if you start with database state X and provide input I, expect output O and new database state X'.  Each time you need to make a change to the legacy codebase, add a new system test.

---

> I was wondering how am I able to cover most of those code even to get an output of a successful result.

I think you have a couple of misconceptions here.

- When unit testing, the percentage of code covered is less important than people expect.  The goal should be to cover the code where the bugs are likely to be.
- *"Successful result"* of what? Of an individual method call?  That assumes that you know what the result *should* be.  That can be difficult, especially if the method has side effects that you aren't aware of or don't understand.

---

One final point is that some code is inherently difficult to write unit tests for.  Typically, it is code that *ought* to be rewritten.  A codebase of 8,700 lines is (realistically) not that large, and could be a candidate for a rewrite.  (You can treat the existing code as a "working prototype" ... in the absence of a decent set of functional requirements.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. This answer will almost certainly over-simplify the nature of your problem you're trying to cover, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

Generally speaking, if I were tasked with covering this code with tests, I'd start by trying to track down some software requirements that thoroughly describe the intended behavior of the software. Then I'd write some high-level integration style tests to cover the intended behavior plus all documented edge-cases. The only stubs I'd use in this test would be for calls to external systems. I wouldn't really be thinking in unit-test terms at this stage.

The trick here is to think about the software you're trying to cover with tests in terms of discreet groups of functionality. Once you've identified those groups, then writing tests for each of those groups becomes a matter of identifying what the boundaries of functionality are, then exercising those pieces of functionality with integration tests. Basically, at this stage, what you should be concerned with are inputs and outputs to systems (or functions, if that level of granularity makes sense), and not be too concerned with the specific implementation details. An example could be: "When I call this function, I expect there to be a new record in the database with these exact properties."

In a complex system, you can definitely expect to see some overlap in your integration tests, but at this stage, that's okay. All you're trying to do is ensure that, as you refactor these long functions into smaller units, the functionality of the system does not change in unintended ways (or break). In other words, you want to ensure that the behavior of the system after you start to refactor these pieces is exactly the same as it was before you started.

Once your integration tests are in place, hopefully you've gotten to know the behavior of the system (or part of the system) well enough that you can identify discreet units of behavior within the large complex functions you referred to in your question. This will also give you an opportunity to extract any duplication which might be present. The more thoroughly your integration tests cover the behavior and edge cases, the more confident you can be in refactoring.

Once you get to this stage and you start to identify individual units of functionality, **then** it makes sense to start thinking about unit tests. This is also the stage when mocking and stubbing makes a lot more sense for testing internal APIs (i.e. mocking inter-domain API boundaries in addition to inter-system API boundaries).

Again - this is a huge over-simplification of a topic that I'm sure entire books have been written on, but I hope this helps you gain some directional insight at a high-level.